# How to retrieve the missing file sources.list in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, list, file, ubuntu, apt

I am getting error message as specified below in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

I am not sure whether i deleted it or it got damaged because of installations.

When i try to list out the directory `/etc/apt`

I can still see `sources.list.d` and `sources.list.save` except `sources.list` which is missing.

So is it possible to retrieve `sources.list` from the available 2 files in the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename `sources.list.save` to `sources.list` . `sources.list.save` is a backup file for `sources.list`. If the `sources.list` file got deleted accidentally, you may use the contents inside the `sources.list.save` file but the file name must be `sources.list` so that Ubuntu would take this file.

Comment: i accidentally deleted the entire apt by mistake...any way to resolve the issue?